# How to use a variable anywhere in the code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In Java EE how can I use a variable anywhere in code without passing it down as a parameter?

Something similar to a public static variable... but a static variable is always the same for all the requests... What about a "static" variable but for the single request?

Is it possible?

Here is a little example:

I have:

```
protected void doGet (...)
{
    Model m = Model.GetById (...);
}

public class Model
{
    private String descrition;
    private Market market;
    private List<SparePart> spareParts;

    public Model GetById ()
    {
        Model m = new Model ();
        // get info from db using the language
        this.market = Market.GetById (...);
        this.spareParts = SparePart.GetByModel (m);
    }
}
public class SparePart
{
    private String description;

    public List<SparePart> GetByModel (Model mo)
    {
        // get info from db using the language
    }
}

public class Market
{
    private String descrition;

    public Market GetById (...)
    {
        // get info from db using the language
    }
}
```

Both make queries to the database and retrieve informations using the language of the client... How can I set the language variable so i don't have to pass it to the methods that use it?

The anguage variable is just an example, it may happen with other variables

Comment: Add it as a request attribute.

Comment: but in that case I'd have to pass down the request, right?

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea.  There's a good reason why people discourage global variables.  Re-examine whatever requirements you are imagining to inspire this.

Comment: Well, you're passing down the request anyway. In most cases through a number of filters and finally to a servlet or JSP page.

Comment: Can you try putting the required variable in a singleton object or a static class and use it through out the flow and reset on next request? You can ues a map to track the variable based on timestamp as key

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy Extremely bad advice.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, please be specific when you comment on the answer as it would help me understand where I am wrong! Can you do that?

Comment: We're talking about a Java EE application server here. What you're suggesting is configuring the server to accept at most one single concurrent request. It defeats the entire point of having an application server in the first place and performance would be abysmal.

Comment: java-ee is very broad, can you narrow your question to a specific framework like: servlet, jsp, jsf... ?

Comment: @tak3shi Doesn't matter. Pretty much everything is servlet in the end. JSP compiles to servlet, and JSF runs on top of the servlet layer.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Does that mean that you are writing a servlet instead of using a class member variable in CDI ?

Comment: CDI is orthogonal to the servlet API. It can be used in pretty much whatever component you need to use it, whether it's a servlet, and EJB, or a POJO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozen ways to pass your data through execution flow in JaveEE applications. Let's assume you need to pass data within one application boundary.

- Of course you can use public static final constants.
- You can use public static variables, but take into account that EE
  environment is extremely multithreaded. So use atomic wrappers
  (AtomicInteger, etc).
- You can use [producers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm#GKGKV)
- While single request scope (http (rest) -> interseptor(s) -> bean(s)
  -> response) you can use ThreadLocal
- Of course you can use Stateful or Singleton beans You can use CDI
  Events
- If you are using Payara Server (for now the only has JCache spec
  preview) you can use [JCache](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jcache_based_configurator_jc2) to share your data among any
  application or along the cluster as well

If you need to share your data between servers you can expose your business methods on @Remote interfaces and or share/publish/consume using JMX.

The concrete choice should depend on your App business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get attributes on your `ServletRequest` object.

```
request.setAttribute("someName", someObject);

Object someObject = request.getAttribute("someName");
```

See the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

Alternatively, you could use [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html) (or another DI framework) and define one or more `@RequestScoped` objects that you can then `@Inject` in the places you need them.

Comment: but I have to pass down the request as a paramter, right?

Comment: Pass down to what?

Comment: down to methods in my classes

Comment: Or just extract what you need from the request and pass that down.

Comment: yes, I know, My question is if I can make them visible in my classes without the need of passing them as parameters. I'll update the question with an example.

Comment: Sounds like bad design. If you want to scope a variable to a single request, the two options I outlined above are pretty much the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Although not passing parameters is not a good idea in the first place, if you 'MUST' find a solution and if it matches your design, how about using inner classes? That way you declare the class variable as non-static and you can always access it from the inner classes.